# $.post() not able to pass data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass some data as a variable using jQuery $.post() method to a PHP file and then display the result in a div after clicking a button. But the data isn't getting retrieved in PHP file.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.post("add.php", {
                fname: 'Billy'
            }, function () {
                $('#topic').load('add.php');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
            echo "Welcome ".get('Name')." !";
        ?>
        <div style="float: right">
            <?php
                echo "<a href='logout.php'> Log Out </a>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button>Add Topic</button><br>
        <div id='topic'></div>
```

//the PHP file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "".$_POST['fname']."";
    //if(isset($_POST['fname']))
    //{
        //$fname=$_POST['fname'];
        //echo " ".$fname." topic added!";
    //}
?>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\add.php on line 3

Comment: Are you sure you get the error after the POST is done? Maybe you get the error when you load the page the first time

Comment: the success-callback ist strange. Why do you do another `.load` after the post? You should read the return from `$.post` and use that to fill #topic

Comment: try this instead: `$.post("add.php", { fname : 'Billy' }, function(response){ $('#topic').html(response);});
                        });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the `load` function, but it seems to me that you're doubling down on fetching from the same resource.

You could do something like:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'add.php',
   data: {fname:"Billy"},
   success: function(response){
        $( "#topic" ).html(response);
        // or .text or whichever replacement method you need/works best
   },
});
```

`add.php`

```
if ( isset($_POST['fname'] ){
    echo "Topic " . $_POST['fname'] . " added!";
} else {
    echo "Could not find 'fname'!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'add.php',
   data: {fname:"your data goes here"},
   success: function(response){
        // handle success
   },
   error: function(response){
        // handle error 
   },
});
```